# Import Magento Orders into Openerp

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, magento-1.9, openerp-7

We are in a process of Integrating Magento 1.9.0.1 with Openerp 7.0 , For that we are using below extensions and addons,

```
  Magento Side - Openlabs Openerpconnector 
  Openerp Side - Magento Integration addon by Openlabs
```

I have done the integration of magento with openerp by creating Api user and Role and I can able to import websites, store view and products into openerp . But I cant able import sale orders from  Magento to Openerp.

The error message is,

```
Fault: <Fault 101: 'Product not exists.'>
```

I have spent 3 days to fix this issue. But no luck .
Any suggestions are greatly welcome !

Thanks in Advance  !

Answer (score 0):

Hi Muthukumar Sivasamy,

Their are multiple solution were proposed to this problem, [check here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/magentoerpconnect/+bug/834619) for patch and explanation.

Bests